# PHP mail attachment is blank

Tags: php, attachment

I got the form to accept an attachment and send the attachment but if it's a doc it's blank:

```
   $fileatt = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
   $fileattType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
   $fileattName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
   $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
   $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
   fclose($file);

   $semi_rand = md5(time());
   $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

   $headers = "from: $email";

   $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
        " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

   $content = "Info about user";

   $content = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
        "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
        "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
        $content . "\n\n";

   $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

   $content .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
        "Content-Type: {$fileattType};\n" .
        " name=\"{$fileattName}\"\n" .
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
        " filename=\"{$fileattName}\"\n" .
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
        $data . "\n\n" .
        "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

   $send = mail( "user@provider.com", "Form", $content, $headers);
         if($send)
            header('Location: success page');
         else
            header('Location: fail page');
```

The email sends correctly, there is an attachment with the correct name, file type, and file size. when it opens it is empty.

I got the tutorial from sitepoint: http://articles.sitep... ... mail-php/5

I tested the files they provide and the same thing happens. Any ideas would be great. thanks everyone!

Comment: This is not PHPBB..... Don't use `[code]` tags.

Comment: I tried my code on an offsite server. I kept the file exactly the same I even left the ini_set calls:

ini_set("SMTP","smtp.server.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","25");
ini_set("sendmail_from","$email");

Leads me to believe the issue is the web server that the php is sitting on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO.

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I would recommend you use a ready-made mailing class like [**PHPMailer**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/). It has all the quirks, encoding and attaching functions already built in, which is much less error-prone than doing it by hand. If you want to go that way, maybe [**this collection of tutorial links**](http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html) on PHPMailer will help you get started.

Comment: I've seen this suggested multiple times on other forums regarding mail handling. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

## Why not use a decent library for sending emails?

I strongly suggest you start using a library for sending emails, it eases the process of writing emails and makes the code a lot more transient.

I can vouch for [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org), an actively developed library with excellent features.

Especially complicated tasks like attachments, inline images and multiple recipients are implemented easily.

Comment: The website of Swiftmailer contains excellent documentation that is both pragmatic and in depth. A quick reference of the library shows you how to create messages: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/message-quickref

Good luck!

Comment: am I required to upload the attachment to my web server before I can send it?

Comment: Any attachments you wish to send should be available to your PHP environment, i.e. a readable directory on your webserver.

Comment: "Why not use a decent library for sending emails?" maybe because decent library like the one you suggested are made by 141 php files, when one short and well written simple script coud be used to send SIMPLE mail with ONE small attachment.

Comment: @Marco Demaio: I guess you don't fancy using libraries in particular. To me it seems strange that people are trying to reinvent functionality while there are perfect _FREE_ libraries out there. Especially in the context of working in teams where libraries not only provide quality tools but also serve as a common grammar and vocabulary for team communication...

Comment: @Marijn Huizendveld, read this: http://reprog.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/whatever-happened-to-programming/

Answer (score 2):

I would **strongly** recommend using a preexisting tool to send emails, such as [Swift](http://swiftmailer.org/). There are a lot of caveats that it will take care of for you, and it's quite easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use `\r\n` instead of those `\n\n`

Comment: +1 the 1st DIRCET answer. It's not enought, but it's a good starting point, you must use "\r\n" and NOT "\n\n".

Answer (score 0):

Answer with code example is here: http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php

Comment: problem is, the php seems to be stripping the header. I placed the php that processes sending the email with attachment on another server and it works perfect.